# Has_many: through in Rails. Can I have two foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a rails newbie and I am trying to create a database schema that looks like the following:

There are many matches. Each match has 2 teams.

A team has many matches.

The team model and match model are joined together through a competition table.

I have that competition model with a match_id and a team1_id and a team2_id.

But I don't know how to make this work or if it's even the best way to go about it. I don't know how to make certain teams team1 and others team2.... two foreign keys? Is that possible?

The match table also needs to hold additional data like team1_points and team2_points, winner and loser, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many foreign keys as you want in a table.  I wrote an application that involved scheduling teams playing in games.

The way that I handled this in the Game class with the following:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => 'Team', :foreign_key => 'team1_id'
  belongs_to :visitor_team, :class_name => 'Team', :foreign_key => 'team2_id'
```

You can add appropriate fields for team1_points, team2_points, etc.  You'll need to set up your Team model with something like:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games, :class_name => 'Game', :foreign_key => 'team1_id'
  has_many :visitor_games, :class_name => 'Game', :foreign_key => 'team2_id'

  def games
    home_games + visitor_games
  end

  #important other logic missing
end
```

Note that some of my naming conventions were the result of having to work with a legacy database.

Comment: This is a great help. Thank you! 

So that I understand fully, this is just a has_many to has_many association, right? Not a has_many :through???

And :home_team and :visitor_team are just basically psuedo models that aren't actual models??? I'm just making that term up but it seems thats what's going on. (Same with :home_games, and :visitor_games for that matter.)

Again, thank you!

Comment: Exactly.  The :class_name tag tells you what model it actually is.  There's no "home_team" model, just a team.  That means that myGame.home_team gives you a reference to a Team object.  If this helps you or answers you question, please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem, and extending the previous answer, what I did was:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.played_by(team)
    where('team1_id = ? OR team2_id = ?', team.id, team.id)
  end
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  def games
    @games ||= Game.played_by(self)
  end
end
```

This way, `Team#games` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instead of an `Array`, so you can keep chaining other scopes.